# FPDF writes to only one line

Tags: python, fpdf

The variable "output" in the code below is a couple of paragraphs of text and I am trying to write it all to a pdf using FPDF. But, it writes to only one line. How do I get it to include line breaks. For example, the text has "\n" in several locations of the text but its ignored. Thank you.

```
dummytext = "line 1" + "\n"
dummytext += "line 2" + "\n"
dummytext += "line 3"

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_xy(0,0)
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt=dummytext, border=0)
pdf.output('testpdf.pdf', 'F')
```

The variable dummytext shows up in the pdf as:

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

Comment: Can you add dummy contents of `output` in the question?

Comment: Added output text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `multi_cell` will facilitate the new lines in `FPDF` output.

> `multi_cell`: This method allows printing text with line breaks.

Details can be found in [Documentation of multi_cell](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/multi_cell/index.html).

`code.py`:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
dummytext = "line 1" + "\n"
dummytext += "line 2" + "\n"
dummytext += "line 3"
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_xy(0,0)
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
pdf.multi_cell(0, 5, dummytext)
pdf.output('testpdf.pdf', 'F')
```

Output:

[image: fpdf newline in output]